# How to validate contenteditable paragraph text length,based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, onkeyup

I need to disable text typing according to text length in `contenteditable` paragraph.

```
<p id="test" class="given" contenteditable="true"></p>
```

Which means I need to avoid typing text,

```
  $("p.given").on('click keydown keyup',function(e) {

    var templateText = getContent($(this)); //Test [FirstName] ! Lorem Ipsum is  [LocationName]. the printing and typesetting.


      // 46,8 keycodes for delete & backspace
    if (templateText.length >= 100  && e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8){
       e.preventDefault();
    }

  });
```

this `getContent()` method returns following sample string outout.

```
Test [FirstName] ! Lorem Ipsum is  [LocationName]. the printing and typesetting.
```

The above `click keydown keyup` function is not working as expected, What I need to do is,

I need to consider `[FirstName]` length as 50
`[LocationName]` length as 60

So then , in order to that, I need to validate text typing. How can I do this

Comment: can you please explain what u r trying to do...?

Comment: How are you isolating [FirstName] and [LocationName] from other textual content in<p> ? Aren't we missing another Regex test here?

Comment: Are you expecting a typed content using brackets in a shortcode like format ? Like the first brackets are for Firstname and the 2nd for LocationName?

Comment: @Bilel yes, there is no regex or another implementation to isolate  [FirstName] and [LocationName]. But I think its should have that type of thing. Can you please provide me an answer.  "Like the first brackets are for Firstname and the 2nd for LocationName?" No, I just need to assume length as 50 for Firstname  and 60 for LocationName.

Answer (score 1):

This example is expecting the first square brackets [] to contain the First name, and the 2nd the LocationName. Both limited appropriately with the values you mentioned above.

```js
$("p.given").on('click paste keydown keyup', function (e) {

  var templateText = $(this).text();
 var fullID = templateText.match(/\[([^\]]+)]/g);
  
  if(fullID.length ==2){
 console.log('All:' + templateText.length + '#Firstname:' + fullID[0].length + '#LocationName:' + fullID[1].length);
    $(this).css("color","black");
 if ((fullID[0].length >= 50 || fullID[1].length >= 60 || templateText.length >= 100) && (e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8))

  {
  return false;
 }
  } else {
  console.log('please Type the firstname and the LocationName between brackets [] ');
  $(this).css("color","red");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" class="given" contenteditable="true">Test [Denzel Washington] ! Lorem Ipsum is  [Hollywood]. the printing and typesetting.</p>
```

Notice:Some of your click/Keycode events won't work on mobile browsers. That's why I tried a mobile-version on Codepen : 
https://codepen.io/bilelh/pen/JjoBRyL